# Determine if a sequence is an interleaving of a repetition of two strings

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity, shuffle, interleave

I have this task:

> Let x be a string over some finite and fixed alphabet (think English alphabet). Given
>   an integer k we use x^k
>   to denote the string obtained by concatenating k copies of x. If x
>   is the string HELLO then x^3
>   is the string HELLOHELLOHELLO. A repetition of x is
>   a prefix of x^k
>   for some integer k. Thus HELL and HELLOHELL are both repetitions of
>   HELLO.
>   An interleaving of two strings x and y is any string that is obtained by shuffling a repetition
>   of x with a repetition of y. For example HELwoLOHELLrldwOH is an interleaving of
>   HELLO and world.
>   Describe an algorithm that takes three strings x, y, z as input and decides whether z is an
>   interleaving of x and y.

I've only come up with a solution, which has exponential complexity (We have pointer to the `z` word, and kind of a binary tree. In every node I have current states of possible words x and y (at the start both blank). I'm processing z, and nodes has one/two/no children depending on if the next character from z could be added to x word, y word or no word.) How could I get better than exponential complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the two words x and y have length N1 and N2.

Construct a non-deterministic finite state machine with states (n1, n2) where 0 <= n1 < N1 and 0 <= n2 < N2. All states are accepting.

Transitions are:

```
c: (n1, n2) --> ((n1 + 1) % N1, n2) if x[n1] == c
c: (n1, n2) --> (n1, (n1 + 1) % n2) if y[n2] == c
```

This NDFSM recognises strings that are formed from interleaving repetitions of x and y.

Here's some ways to implement the NDFSM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Implementation

Here's a simple Python implementation.

```
def is_interleaved(x, y, z):
    states = set([(0, 0)])
    for c in z:
        ns = set()
        for i1, i2 in states:
            if c == x[i1]:
                ns.add(((i1+1)%len(x), i2))
            if c == y[i2]:
                ns.add((i1, (i2+1)%len(y)))
        states = ns
    return bool(states)

print is_interleaved('HELLO', 'world', 'HELwoLOHELLrldwOH')
print is_interleaved('HELLO', 'world', 'HELwoLOHELLrldwOHr')
print is_interleaved('aaab', 'aac', 'aaaabaacaab')
```

In the worst case, it'll run in O(N1 * N2 * len(z)) time and will use O(N1 * N2) space, but for many cases, the time complexity will better than this unless the strings x and y are repetitious.